# When installing mega sync on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Tags: 20.04, mega

```
sudo apt install ./megasync-xUbuntu_21.04_amd64.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'megasync' instead of './megasync-xUbuntu_21.04_amd64.deb'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 megasync : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.33) but 2.31-0ubuntu9.2 is to be installed
            Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.15.1) but 5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
            Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.14.1) but 5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu1 is to be installed or
                     libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.14.1) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libqt5network5 (>= 5.14.1) but 5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
            Depends: libraw20 (>= 0.16.0) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Any guide/suggestions?

Comment: Whatever that "megasync" is, it is for 21.04, and not for 20.04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are downloading MEGA version for wrong OS version. Ubuntu 21.04 and Ubuntu 20.04 LTS are not compatible in many libraries.

You have to explicitly specify that you need a package for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS:

> [image: mega for 20.04] on https://mega.io/sync

and then install *megasync-xUbuntu_**20.04**_amd64.deb* file.